# Magento 2 - Cache warmer for multiple server

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cache, cronjobs, cache-warmer

I have integrated a [cache warmer](https://github.com/igorppbr/magento2-warmcache) module. Using **cronjob** it runs and creates `cache` for **all the pages**, and it's working properly.

I have **multiple servers** (Let's say 2 servers), until now there is no need to `schedule cronjobs` for all `servers`, I used to `schedule cronjobs` only on first server.

Since cache used **local storage** to save **cached data**, if I **schedule cronjob** on one server, then **cache warmer** wont work on other server.

Now my question is, **how can I create cache for both servers while cron is scheduled on first server**

Comment: how often do you run the cache warmer? I am not sure what the default expiry time for cached varnished pages is and how often to warm the cache.

Comment: every 24 hours is best time for cache, in addition I have created a command to warm cache. So when I flush cache I can also warm it with command line

Comment: so default ttl for varnish pages is 24 hours?

Comment: Sorry, don't know exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In local cache environment it is impossible to create cache for both servers while executing cron on one server.

There is only one option left, **make cache centralize**.

To do this you need to use either **Varnish** or **Redis**. I have read multiple articles and all of them saying that **Varnish** is better approach. But I have used **AWS Elasticache Redis** on my server as it is more cheap and I have less knowledge of Varnish right now :D

To implement redis I have executed this command on shell (Putty)

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --page-cache=redis --page-cache-redis-server=127.0.0.1 --page-cache-redis-db=1
```

I have used my server details in above command (Obviously)

And now I have centralized storage of Full Page Cache, and I have scheduled cronjob on one server and it is working fine for both servers.